# Extend mysql 5.5 tablespace to another drive on windows

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have greater than 300gb mysql database which is running out of disk space in D: drive on windows.( Presently the ibd data file is in D: drive which is running out of space). I have a F: drive which is having around 200 GB free space.

1)How can i extend the ibd data file to f: drive so that all new inserts go in f drive ? 
Variable innodb_file_per_table is OFF currently.
Innodb_data_filepath : ibdtaxx:10M:autoextend

Please leave your suggestions on what will be the best course of action to follow in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql` have "working dir" where all the schemas' dirs are stored. You have to:

- stop your `mysql`
- move the dir with desired schema to the new huge drive

`mv D:\path\to\workingdir\dbschema F:\dbschema`

- make the link from the new location to the old working dir:

`mklink \D F:\dbschema D:\path\to\workingdir\dbschema`

- start your `mysql`

Test that approach on some noncritical schema, indeed.